# Angular modal directive - issue when having more than 1 in a page

Tags: angularjs, directive

I made a modal directive for my angular app.

`modal-directive.js`

```
'use strict';

backyApp.directive('appModal', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        link: function($scope, elem, attr){
            $scope.modalClass = attr.appModal;
        },
        scope: '@',
        templateUrl: './components/modal/modal.html'
    };
});
```

and the template looks like this: (`modal.html`)

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="app-modal" ng-class="modalClass">
    <div ng-transclude></div>            
</div>
```

Now, let's pretend we have 2 modals in a page:

```
<div app-modal="firstModal">
    <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text"  />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div app-modal="secondModal">
    <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text"  />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Problem:** I end up with 2 modals having the same class (in my example above, `secondModal` will be attached to 2 of my modals)

Why does this happen? I need the value of my directive to be attached to each modal because thats the only way I can open the one I want.

I know this is horrible explanation Let me know if you have any question

**Edit:**

I want to have 2 `app-modal` divs, each one having its directive value as a class attached to it. Hope it's more clear now.

Comment: What's `scope: '@',`? Try removing it

Comment: I'm already able to pass the values `firstModal` and `secondModal`. At the end I need two `app-modal` having each of my directive values.

Comment: Alon Eitan - I tried, no success. But anyway, I need it to pass variables to my directive template

Comment: Any chance for a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Below you can see a plunker, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use an isolated scope in the directive

```
backyApp.directive('appModal', function() {
 return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: true,
    link: function($scope, elem, attr){
        $scope.modalClass = attr.appModal;
    },
    scope: {},
    templateUrl: './components/modal/modal.html'
 };
});
```

Here is a plunker I did for this
https://embed.plnkr.co/UwjBIqTh5fNlAcbIs6TS/

Comment: you already solved the problem of having duplicated classes! thank you! I only have one problem unsolved. I tried to edit your plunker - but I don't know how to save so I'll explain: Let's wrap our first `form-group` div in the first modal with a form and when submitting, I want to alert the value of the input text there. How can I access that? (I previously relied on `'@'` for that.) I need to access my modal's text fields from my main controller